# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException when call getBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, vaadin

I integrated `spring security` in to [More-Vaadin/springsecurity-integration](https://github.com/nfrankel/More-Vaadin/tree/master/springsecurity-integration)
The version of Vaadin is older there so I rewrite some of its elements using newer VaadinVersion.

But the problem is that during authentication in this method I catch the exception.

```
public void handleAuthentication(String username, String password, HttpServletRequest request) {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

    token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    ServletContext servletContext = session.getServletContext();
    WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    AuthenticationManager authManager = wac.getBean(ProviderManager.class); //exception
    Authentication authentication = authManager.authenticate(token);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
}
```

I've got `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` in `wac.getBean` line

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.
authentication.AuthenticationManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: org.springframework.security.au
thentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.spr
ingframework.security.authenticationManager
```

When I try to use `ProvideManager.class` I get the same exception. 
My `context` file looks like this

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>

    <http pattern="/VAADIN/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/static/**" security="none"/>

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" password="admin"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
            <filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter"/>
        </filter-chain-map>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter"/>

</beans:beans>
```

What is the problem? I did not implemeneted any `AuthenticationManager` myself.

Comment: Maybe there are other classes that implement the `ProviderManager` interface? Did you try with the `AuthenticationManager` type? `AuthenticationManager authManager = wac.getBean(AuthenticationManager.class);`

Comment: It was exception with `AuthenticationManager` at first. I changed to `ProviderManager` and it remained the same

Comment: I see nothing wrong in the code you posted. Try to remove parts of your config and to locate when the other AuthenticationManagers are instantiated... Maybe scanned from annotations? Maybe auto-created in a config you imported?

Comment: Well it seems it really problem with configuration and especially with `authentication-manager` config...

Answer (score 0):

Why not named your authenticationManager like this ? 
`<authentication-manager alias="myAuthenticationManager">`

And call it like that : `wac.getBean("myAuthenticationManager");`